# Open source library/framework for building dashboard (bar,line,pie,etc)

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, dashboard

I have done POC with highcharts and works fine and looks great.

I am looking for better open source library/framework using which i can develop my dashboard showing different graphs.

The UI framework must handle the real time data (like Ajax calls or REST).

Any helpful suggestion appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.flotcharts.org/ provides a popular open source javascript charts library.

Comment: You have mentioned it as open source,but on site i cannot find is it under MIT license something like that.

Comment: Also i noticed it doesn have touch sensitivity, which is important factor

Comment: seems to be a non-named open source license: https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/LICENSE.txt

Comment: @Rory That is the MIT license: http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT

Answer (score 9):

[D3 (Data-Driven Documents)](http://d3js.org/) is excellent if you have a bit of time to learn it.

Some examples:

http://bl.ocks.org/3287802

http://jondot.github.com/graphene/

Comment: You can also consider using a hybrid solution where you use D3 to handle your data/DOM manipulation and [raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/) as your drawing API/polyfill.

Answer (score 8):

After you pick your graphing solution (plots, charts, ...) some drag-and-droop grid to put it all together on one dashboard:

- [gridster.js](http://gridster.net) (MIT licensed) may come in handy
- [Packery](http://packery.metafizzy.co) non-profit GPL v3 licensed or one-time purchase for a commercial license

Comment: This can be handy only when i need to integrate my all charts under one roof. I dont think it can be useful as chart lib.

Comment: While I agree these are a bit off topic, they are awesome and I have not found them anywhere else. So thanks lukmdo!

Answer (score 5):

here's another awesome looking one (quite win8 themed) : [dashing](http://shopify.github.com/dashing/)

Comment: It really appeared cool to me,yet i am wondering if it supports an  api's  to connect to an application servers like weblogic or graphite which collects data and manages data as per our queries. Also i cannot find the documentation where i can see the different charts i can built on top of it.

Comment: Dashing looks great. It's a dashboard framework rather than just charting. I think they have some chart widgets that use https://github.com/shutterstock/rickshaw and you can build your own widgets that use whatever charting library you want (no idea yet how easy that is - it'd be really nice to see an example of flot charts with Dashing for example).

Comment: Here's some docs on including highchart widgets https://github.com/Shopify/dashing/issues/42. Presumably it'd be simple to include other (open source) frameworks too.

Comment: Can i use Dashing with ASP.NET MVC, it looks like it can be used only with Ruby ? Not sure ...

Answer (score 3):

There are many charts plugins out there. http://www.queness.com/post/10781/13-chart-and-graph-plotting-javascript-plugins

My recommendations:

[JQPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/): jQuery plugin. Uses canvas element or VML
[gRaphael](http://g.raphaeljs.com/): uses raphaeljs JS library. SVG W3C Recommendation and VML as a base for creating graphics. - Lots of options.

Comment: What you have recomended does it cover real time data feed,(can i have ajax calls or someting) so my chart looks real up and running?

Answer (score 2):

If you only need an charts api
try https://developers.google.com/chart/

Its also support real-time updates

Comment: I guess these do not require any licensing in production??

Comment: You can use it in production. But may have some limitations with api calls. you can read the tos if you need more info on licensing. 
https://developers.google.com/terms/

Comment: ok.. i will have look into it.
Thanks